# Applying the Addition Rule Where Second Probability is Conditional

Tags: probability, arithmetic

If a first event A has an impact on the probability of a second event B, how do we apply the addition rule for probability?

Problem: Find the probability of drawing a club from a full deck of cards in two draws, without replacement. Use the addition rule $P(\text{A} \cup \text{B}) = P(\text{A}) + P(\text{B}) - P(\text{A} \cap \text{B})$.

Question: What to plug in for $P(\text{B})$, in this particular situation?

Let $P(\text{A})$ = probability of getting a club on the first draw, and $P(\text{B})$ = probability of getting a club on the second draw.

$P(\text{A})$ is straightforward: $\frac {13}{52}$ = $\frac 14$ = 0.25.

$P(\text{B})$ is theoretically the same. But in fact, the first draw reduced the deck by one card, and the new conditional probability depends on whether the first draw was a club. So it is either equivalent to $P(\text{B | A})$ = $\frac {13 - 1}{51}$ = $\frac {12}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.2353, if a club, or, if not, it is equivalent to $P(\text{B | A}^c)$ = $\frac {13}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.2549. Which of these three — the ideal/"true" probability, or either of the real probabilities — becomes $P(\text{B})$ in the standard formula?

If, instead of using the addition rule, we build up our answer by analyzing the sample space outcome by outcome, we reach the following result.

Probabilities to be used:

$P(\text {club on 1st draw})$ = $P(\text{A})$ = 0.25

$P(\text {non-club on 1st draw})$ = $P(\text{A}^c)$ = 0.75

$P(\text {club on 2nd draw, given club on 1st})$ = $P(\text{B | A})$ = $\frac {13 - 1}{51}$ = $\frac {12}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.2353

$P(\text {club on 2nd draw, given non-club on 1st})$ = $P(\text{B | A}^c)$ = $\frac {13}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.2549

$P(\text {non-club on 2nd draw, given club on 1st})$ = $P(\text{B}^c | {A})$ = $\frac {51 - 12}{51}$ = $\frac {39}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.7647

$P(\text {non-club on 2nd draw, given non-club on 1st})$ = $P(\text{B}^c | {A}^c)$ = $\frac {51 - 13}{51}$ = $\frac {38}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.7451

Four possible outcomes of two draws from the deck:

A. Non-club 1st draw, non-club 2nd draw: prob. $P(\text{A}^c)P(\text{B}^c | {A}^c)$ = $\frac 34 \times \frac {38}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.5588

B. Non-club 1st draw, club 2nd draw: prob. $P(\text{A}^c)P(\text{B} | {A}^c)$ = $\frac 34 \times \frac {13}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.1912

C. Club 1st draw, non-club 2nd draw: prob. $P(\text{A})P(\text{B}^c | {A})$ = $\frac 14 \times \frac {39}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.1912

D. Club 1st draw, club 2nd draw: prob. $P(\text{A})P(\text{B} | {A})$ = $\frac 14 \times \frac {12}{51}$ $\approx$ 0.0588

These probabilities add up to 1.000, and so comprise the entire sample space.

Adding together the three possibilities for drawing a club, we have 0.1912 + 0.1912 + 0.0588 = 0.4412, or a probability of 44.12% of getting at least one club in two draws.

Going back to the addition rule, the only way to obtain the right answer seems to be to use the ideal/"true" value for $P(\text {B})$.

We can rewrite the addition rule

$P(\text{A} \cup \text{B}) = P(\text{A}) + P(\text{B}) - P(\text{A} \cap \text{B})$

by substituting the multiplication rule for the subtrahend, as follows:

$P(\text{A} \cup \text{B}) = P(\text{A}) + P(\text{B}) - P(\text{A})P(\text{B} | A)$. Then, putting in the ideal/"true" value for $P(\text B)$, we have

$P(\text{A} \cup \text{B}) = \frac 14 + \frac 14 - \frac 14 \times \frac {12}{51}$ = 0.25 + 0.25 - (0.25)(0.2353) = 0.5 - 0.0588 = 0.4412.

But why would this be?

Comment: $P(B)$ is the probability that the second draw is clubs, which is just $\frac 14$.

Comment: Note:  it's much easier, conceptually, to work this problem backwards.  That is, compute the probability that you draw non-clubs twice in a row and subtract from $1$.  Definitely worth doing it that way.  Then, at a minimum, you have something to compare to the answer you get by other means.

Comment: For the broader question of how to compute (for example) $ ~p(A) + p(B) - p(A \cap B), ~$  when $~A,B~$ are not independent events, see [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).  So, you would compute $~p(A)~$ and $~p(B),~$ each independent of the other.  Then, you could compute $$p(A \cap B) = p(A) \times p(B|A).$$

Comment: You could also address this question by making $A$ the event that you draw a club, then any other card, and $B$ the event that you draw a non-club, then a club. Now $A$ and $B$ are independent events, and each is easily calculated $P(A)$ is still $\frac 14$, while $P(B) = \frac 34\cdot \frac{13}{51} = \frac{13}{68}$.